# display an image in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to display images with c# with `PictureBox` . I've created an class that contians a `pictureBox` and a timer. but when create object from that nothing display.

what should i do?

am I using timer1 correctly?

Here is my code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c1 c = new c1();
        c.create_move(1);
    }

}

class c1 {

    PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();

    public void create_move(int i){

        p.ImageLocation = "1.png";
        p.Location = new Point(50, 50 + (i - 1) * 50);

        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Interval = 15;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    }


    private int k = 0;
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         // some code. this part work outside the class c1 properly.
         ...

    }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to add the picture box to a `Form`. Check out the `Form.Controls.Add()` method.

Answer (score 7):

It's because your pictureboxes are not added to the current form.

You have a `Form.Controls` property, which has a `Add()` method.

Comment: Where I should put that? I wrote Form1.Controls.Add(p) in move_create() method but gave error...

Comment: You need a reference to your form.  Either pass it in the constructor of your class, of with a property.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the `Timer` is enabled.  You might need to do `timer1.Enabled = true;` before you call the `Start()` method.

Answer (score 2):

First of all - you will have to add the pictureBox(es) to the form, if you want them to show up. Anyway - I would try/recommend to create a **userControl**. Add a *PictureBox* to your new control, and a *TimerControl*.

```
public partial class MovieControl : UserControl
{
    // PictureBox and Timer added in designer!

    public MovieControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void CreateMovie(int i)
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "1.png";
        pictureBox1.Location = new Point(50, 50 + (i - 1) * 50);

        // set Interval BEFORE starting timer!
        timer1.Interval = 15;
        timer1.Start();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }

    void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // some code. this part work outside 
    }
}
```

Add this new Control to the forms.controls collection and that's it!

```
class Form1
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MovieControl mc = new MovieControl();
        mc.CreateMovie(1);
        this.Controls.Add(mc); /// VITAL!!
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is good practice for the situation, only missing dispose method which is essential in a control with timer.